# Spring ServiceFacade

Tags: spring

Sorry for potentially a silly question - but is it acceptable with Spring to create a one dedicated service, let's say `ServiceFacade`, inject 20-30 other services into it and then pass such a `ServiceFacade` reference as a parameter to different business logic? Will such approach lead to issues within the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, Spring will correctly handle a bean with 20-30 other dependencies. However it is discouraged from a design point of view. Instead of one `ServiceFacade` you might have multiple facades, each with manageable number of dependencies, e.g. 5 and a factory returning different facades instances.

Comment: I absolutely agree from the design point of view. How about from the performance point of view? will it affect the system somehow?

Comment: @alexanoid No, plus if `ServiceFacade` is a singleton (default Spring bean scope) it will be instantiated just once during a container startup, so later it does not matter if the facade has 1 or 30 dependencies.